# R shiny overriding CSS file in header

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm including a CSS file in a shiny app.  I include it in the ui() function prior to including a header that attempts to override the CSS file.  Everything I've read indicates that the header CSS declaration should override the CSS file.  However it is not overriding it unless I use the "!important" rule after the header CSS declaration.  Here's the CSS file (named temp.css):

```
 .btn-default {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #464545;
    border-color: #464545;
 }
```

and here is the R shiny file (named app.R):

```
library(shiny) 

shinyApp(
   ui <- shinyUI(
      fluidPage( 

         # # Set up the basic CSS styling.
         includeCSS("temp.css"),

         # HTML header with style specifications.
         tags$head(
            tags$style(

               # Colorize the actionButton.
               HTML(".btn-default {
                         background-color: rgb(40,110,5);
                         color: rgb(199,207,111);
                     }"
               )
            )
         ),
         fluidRow(
            sidebarPanel(

               # Insert a button.
               actionButton(
                  inputId = "testButton", 
                  label = "Click Here"
               )
            )
         )
      )
   ),

   server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   })
)
```

The CSS declarations in the header for .btn-default take effect for the actionButton if any of the following are done:

1. the !important rule follows the CSS declarations in the header;
2. the temp.css file is not included; or
3. the header declaration is for the button name, using:

   ```
              HTML("#testButton {
                        background-color: rgb(40,110,5);
                        color: rgb(199,207,111);
                    }"
   ```

I've also tried including other selectors in the header CSS, such as `.btn` and `.action-button`.

Is there something else I should be doing?  Is this a shiny problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work the way you expect it if you put `includeCSS("temp.css"),` in your head tag. I am no expert but I think everything in `tag$head` is evaluated first and is overwritten by everything else.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I needed to do. I moved the `includeCSS()` line between the `tags$head()` and `tags$style()` lines, and everything works as expected.

Comment: This was very useful. After several days trying, the only way I was able to force an override of some `!important` tags in the standard loaded dataTable css (it seems the jquery css overrides any custom css file included in this instance) was to stick those tags needing to override the `!important` tags in several `tags$style(HTML(...))` lines.