# Prevent dynamic Shiny CSS files from overwriting each other

Tags: css, r, dynamic, shiny, themes

I've created a Shiny app that allows for dynamic selection of [Bootswatch themes](https://bootswatch.com/). The dynamic selection occurs in the server.R file using `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "..."))` with each .css file saved in my app's `www` directory as "themename.min.css." Here's a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(

    # style ui output (changed on server side )
    uiOutput("style"), 

    # navigation toolbar
    navbarPage(id = "navbar",
               title = "Themes",
               position = "fixed-top",
               collapsible = T,
               navbarMenu(title = "Theme Selector",
                          tabPanel("Cosmo", value = "cosmo"),
                          tabPanel("Journal", value = "journal"),
                          tabPanel("Slate", value = "slate"),
                          tabPanel("United", value = "united"))
    )  # END NAVBAR PAGE 
  ),  # END UI

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    # dynamically update bootswatch theme
    output$style <- renderUI({

      # themes 
      themes <- c("cosmo", "journal", "slate", "united")

      # loop through layouts and apply css file accordingly
      for(i in 1:length(themes)){
        if(input$navbar == themes[i]){
          return(tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = paste0(themes[i], ".min.css"))))
        }
      }  # END LOOP
    })  # END RENDER UI

  }  # END SERVER
)  # END SHINY APP
```

So in this example, I have the 4 themes saved in my `www` directory as "cosmo.min.css," "journal.min.css," etc. The dynamic selection of themes *does* work in a sense--the themes do change as the user selects them from the navigation bar dropdown menu. BUT it seems that certain CSS elements overwrite others as the user changes theme selections. For example, the Slate theme has a gray/silvery navbar. After I select that theme, all subsequent theme selections display that same silver navbar. Each theme works individually, but selecting them dynamically causes issues.

It seems that [using `tags$head` overwrites certain elements from each CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850225/r-shiny-overriding-css-file-in-header)? But I can't seem to use `includeCSS` in the server.R file to make the selection dynamic, but I also don't know how to make the theme selection dynamic in the ui.R file.

I am familiar with the `shinythemes` package, which does have a dynamic theme selector, but the package explicitly states that this function is only to be used in development, whereas I want to deploy my theme-selector application. I checked out the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/shinythemes/blob/master/R/shinytheme.R) for that function, but I don't know Javascript to be able to tailor it to my specific needs.

Comment: It's probably recommending development only because you will run into caching issues on a live site; as your live site wants to hold onto the old styles while you're giving it new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using `includeCSS` instead of HTML tags to reference the stylesheet.

```
for(i in 1:length(themes)){
  if(!is.null(input$themes)){
    if(input$themes == themes[i]){
      return(includeCSS(paste0("www/", themes[i], ".css")))
    }
  }
}  # END LOOP
```